# Can't link other projects in my solution with premake

Tags: c++, premake

I'm trying to get started with premake but I can't get my test project to link properly with it. If I link it manual it works fine though.

I'm using premake 4.3 (also tested it with premake 4.4) on OS X 10.9 with clang 3.4.

After I create a makefile via "premake4 gmake" and try to compile it I get an error like this:

```
Linking subproject
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libsubproject.dylib] Error 1
make: *** [subproject] Error 2
```

My pretty simple project setup:

```
project/
    src/
        test.cpp
    subproject/
        include/
            Library.hpp
        source/
            Library.cpp
    premake4.lua
```

premake4.lua

```
solution "testa"
    configurations {"debug"}
    language "C++"

    includedirs {"subproject/include"}

    project "subproject"
        kind "SharedLib"
        files {"subproject/source/*.cpp"}

    project "main"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        files {"src/*.cpp"}

        links {"subproject"}
```

src/test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Library.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    Library lib(13, 3);

    lib.do_stuff(7);

    return 0;
}
```

subproject/include/Library.hpp

```
#ifndef __LIBRARY_HPP__
#define __LIBRARY_HPP__

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Library {
public:
    Library(int, int);
    void do_stuff(int) const;

private:
    int x;
    int y;

};

#endif
```

subproject/source/Library.cpp

```
#include <Library.hpp>

Library::Library(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Library::do_stuff(int z) const {
    cout << "X: " << x << "Y: " << y << "Z: " << z << endl;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [This Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=internal+error%3A+atom+not+found+in+symbolIndex) seems to point to a bug in Clang related to dead code stripping. Though I have not yet been able to figure out the magic build flags required to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known premake bug. It was reported and fixed, but a fixed version of the program has not been released yet. See the discussion [here](http://industriousone.com/topic/how-remove-flags-ldflags).

This bug is caused by `-Wl,-x` linker flags that premake will add by default to the `project.make` makefile. As of now, there are two possible solutions, download the updated premake source with the fix, compile it and install the new version, or, manually change the value of `LDFLAGS` in the generated `project.make` after each run of premake.

I have also tried the suggestion they give in the link above of setting `premake.tools.gcc.ldflags.flags._Symbols` to `nil`, but it had no effect on my system.